# Fermat's Equation on Integral Matrices

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Can sombebody help me with the following question?

I'm trying to study the Fermat´s equation $X^{n}+Y^{n}=Z^{n}$ over some non-conmutative rings such as $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$. Are there solutions? What are all the solutions? On the other hand: it would be interesting study that equation over the ring $\mathbb{H}$ of Hamilton's quaternions?

I want to write my first paper on some Diophantine equations on different rings, specially different from $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Choose any three matrices $X,Y,Z$ for which $X^2=Y^2=Z^2=0$ (the zero matrix). This gives infinitely many solutions for $n\ge2$.

Comment: Thank yoou Peter, but that are not the all solutions. I want to find all the solutions

Comment: I'm just edit my question. Thank you again.